# 2 domains 1 Ubuntu 2 Spring servers

Tags: server, java, redirect

I have 2 domains reditected (using A record) to one IP where Ubuntu server lives. All incoming requests go to running Spring Boot on port 80 (which works now). But I would like to run 2 Spring Boot apps. The first one for request using domain1.com and the second for requests using domain2.com.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Server runs on Ubuntu 18